# Viewer after ver. 7.37 -- use setAggregatedProperties

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using a custom property panel.
There is any sample of how to replace older "setProperties" with new "setAggregatedProperties" in the viewer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sample is using it: https://forge-extensions.autodesk.io/?extension=CustomPropertiesExtension
Source code: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/blob/master/public/extensions/CustomPropertiesExtension/contents/main.js

```
class CustomPropertyPanel extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerPropertyPanel {
    constructor (viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);
        this.properties = options.properties || {};
    }

    setAggregatedProperties(propertySet) {
        Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerPropertyPanel.prototype.setAggregatedProperties.call(this, propertySet);

        // add your custom properties here
        const dbids = propertySet.getDbIds();
        dbids.forEach(id => {
            var propsForObject = this.properties[id.toString()];
            if (propsForObject) {
                for (const groupName in propsForObject) {
                    const group = propsForObject[groupName];
                    for (const propName in group) {
                        const prop = group[propName];
                        this.addProperty(propName, prop, groupName);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you Adam.
In these days i have already found your project
 https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions/blob/master/public/extensions/CustomPropertiesExtension/contents/main.js

With your code now I have understood how use aggregateProperties