# Forge viewer properties won't reflect the updated info

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I just realized that sometimes Forge viewer OOTB Properties button won't reflect the updated info, any clue why it happens and how to fix it? thanks

Comment: That might refer to the thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67188471/viewer-after-ver-7-37-use-setaggregatedproperties

Could you please confirm?

Comment: Could you please, specify with more context? What exactly is happening? (Viewer version, how you're acquiring those properties...) If you prefer, you can share additional information through forge[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com

Comment: works OK now, didn't expect such simple solution, thanks again Joao!